# API request modification

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, authorization

I am building an API that returns data about companies
Multiple applications will access the API, some of these applications will have access to one company, some to multiple companies.
When a request is recieved for data, an ApplicationApiKey is also sent. I check if the ApiKey has access to the company data.
THis works great for the applications that are allowed access to one company, however an ApplicationApiKey may have access to multiple companies.

A user from Company1 could log in to the application and send a request to https://myapi.com/ticketrequest?timestamp=20140808&ticket=123. 
The user could update to ticket parameter to a different number. This could be the ticket number of a different company that the Application is authorized to access but the logged in user is not. 
How do I stop  users modifying this url to a ticket number of a different company?

These are my thoughts so far:

1. It is enough having my API accessible via SSL only
2. Ask the application developer to encrypt the parameters. 
   https://myapi.com/ticketrequest?re1=ABNFOPO6KJGFD8JGFADIP, This seems feasible for GET requests but what about POSTs.
3. Not my problem, its up to the app developer (until something happens when it will be)
4. My whole process is wrong, it should be one APIKey per company (but this is not possible as applications may add and remove users from different companies)

Thanks for any replies

Comment: Can you ... just store which ApiKeys are allowed access to which companies?

Comment: the API does this. It knows that a key and therefore an application has access to companyids=1,2,3.
However, the user that is logged into the application may only have access to companyid=1 and may modify the url to contain a companyid=2 parameter.

The API will then allow access (correctly) as the APIKey is authorized. I What would like to know what can the application  do to prevent the user doing this.

Comment: 0. Ask the application developer to [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) the parameters.

Comment: Your problem is that the API keys are predictable. Make them a non predictable and you've mitigated the issue. Use non sequential random 16 digit strings. Now, the real issue is client applications will have to hardcode this value, which makes theft a very real possibility. For this, you should auth users against API keys.

Comment: The API key is a GUID and is unique per application.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is a problem of authorization.

1. SSL has nothing to do with your problem. While you must use SSL to protect your data from leaking and tampering, it will not help in any way to solve your authorization problems.
2. Encrypting the parameters is insufficient. It will keep the common user from tampering with the parameters, but it will not stop any sophisticated attacker from reverse engineering your client application and extracting the encryption key - hence gaining the ability to tamper the params even if encrypted.

IMHO your whole concept of authorizing an application is wrong. If you really care about data breach between companies you should implement authorization in the user level. Each user of the application should authenticate himself and you should have some mechanism of authorizing user's to access company data.

Comment: Authorizing at the user(person) level is not possible as an application may not have a login per user. There may just be a company login or it may just be a service retrieving data from the api. I guess you mean that it should be at the most granular level which I agree with and was originally thinking of as the company.

Comment: Since I posted the question I  have thought about this a lot and discussed it with others and have now come to think that the most granular level is the Application. The API will give information to the application, it is up to the application to make sure that the correct users see the correct information. I am shifting the responsibility for a data breach between companies away from the API and on to the application. 
Reverse engineering of the application worries me a little, however, given the setup I see no way around this that does not involve storing some secret key within the app code.